# How Set And Get data using the same Dependency Property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I am working on a WPF project. And I just created a dependency property. This dependency property is intended to make the `RichTextBox.Selection.Text` property **bindeable**.

But what I cannot do is get and set data to `RichTextBox.Selection.Text` using the same DP.

This is the code that I used if I **ONLY** want to get data from my `RichTextBox.Selection.Text` using binding:

```
public class MyRichTextBox: RichTextBox
{

   public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MyRichTextBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                TextPropertyCallback));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public MyRichTextBox()
    {         
        this.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(MyRichTextBox_TextChanged);
    }

    void MyRichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Text = this.Selection.Text;
    }
```

And it works perfectly, but with this code I cannot send any data from my ViewModel class.

So, if I **ONLY** want to set data to the `RichTextBox.Selection.Text` property from my ViewModel I used this code:

```
public class MyRichTextBox: RichTextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(MyRichTextBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            TextPropertyCallback));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void TextPropertyCallback(DependencyObject controlInstance, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        MyRichTextBox instance = (MyRichTextBox)controlInstance;
        instance.Selection.Text = (String)args.NewValue;
    }
```

So, **What Can I do if I want to be able to get and set data using the same dependency property???**

Hope someone can help me, tahnk you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding your input control's text to the VM's property, you have binded an attached property to it, and in that attached property's value changed you set the input control's text.

In other words - there is nothing monitoring the changed to the input control's text.

Edit:

You are still doing:

```
instance.Selection.Text = (String)args.NewValue;
```

However, there is no notification of change to `instance.Selection.Text`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I have used a non-attached property, instead of that I created a class that inherited frrom the RichTextBox, but I am still having the same problem. I have edited my question with my another try

Comment: Yes, I use the event `TextChanged`, but If I use this event and the callback, a infinite loop is created

Comment: Compare with the current value to break the loop.